# New SQL PDO query from result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm very new to PDO SQL queries. I have the following code which works well. When the result returns only 1 row, I then want to set that row to `valid = FALSE"`. How do I do that?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `passcodes` WHERE `passcode` = '$passcode' AND `valid` = TRUE";
$stmt = $DBcon->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
if($count == 1) {
    //do this
} else {
    //do that
}
```

Comment: You're already using `prepare()` - why not use placeholders on variables, and thus preventing SQL injection? That being said, you'll just need to run an update query if the count is 1.

Comment: Please [learn how to use PDO properly](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#prepared)

Comment: PDO is not a framework or an ORM. It's merely a library to run regular SQL code.

Comment: Thanks @YourCommonSense, I've been using PDO statements for the first time in this project, and this is the first instance where I've used a variable in a statement, so good to get on top of bad habits early. Thanks! Out of interest, is there still a problem with nesting `$passcode` considering the following? `function clean($data) { $data = trim($data); $data = stripslashes($data); $data = htmlspecialchars($data); return $data; } $passcode = clean($_POST["passcode"]);`

Comment: @Brad yes, of course. In short, this function clean() rather makes no sense at all. Every function used in it doesn't make anything "clean" but rather  being either harmful or useless for PDO. You can use trim() if you wish, but both stripslashes and htmlspecialchars will do more harm than good.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, thanks for the info. I'm very much a beginner when it comes to databases. Thankfully the world would keep spinning if one of my databases was ever taken down!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I then want to set that row to valid = FALSE". How do I do that?

this is what SQL is for.

```
$sql = "UPDATE `passcodes` SET `valid` = FALSE WHERE `passcode` = ? AND `valid` = TRUE";
$DBcon->prepare($sql)->execute([$passcode]);
```

this is all the code you need.

Comment: What about section "else do that" ?

Comment: If the OP will ask for that, there is an obvious solution you should be aware of as well.

Comment: @artoodetoo Op only wants the sql Query to update. so whats your reason to downvote if its u?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Do you see whole question?

Comment: *When the result returns only 1 row, I then want to set that row to valid = FALSE". How do I do that?*

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile sweet, continue reading please. There is a peace of code which is part of question.

Comment: Thanks for the passion in these comments! I actually have the `else` section covered - it returns an error if there are either 0 rows returned (no matching passcode which is valid) or >1 rows returned (2 passcodes the same: hopefully impossible in a unique column!)

Comment: @Brad yes, it's impossible for the unique column, so you can use rowCount for the else part

Answer (score 2):

Yet another solution.

**IF** you interested in "else" section mentioned above, you can combine elegant solution from @YourCommonSense with checking how much rows was changed in UPDATE. MySQL returns such info!

```
$sql = "UPDATE `passcodes` SET `valid` = FALSE WHERE `passcode` = ? AND `valid` = TRUE";
$DBcon->prepare($sql)->execute([$passcode]);
if ($stmt->rowCount() == 0) {
  // do this when nothing found
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work with count of result rows equal or greater than 1. 
I recommend to use placeholders for prepared statements:

```
$sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `passcodes` WHERE `passcode` = ? AND `valid` = TRUE";
$stmt = $DBcon->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([ $passcode ]);
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($rows) {
    //do this
    $sql = "UPDATE `passcodes` SET `valid` = FALSE WHERE `id` = ?";
    $stmt = $DBcon->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($rows as $r) {
        $stmt->execute([ $r['id'] ]);
    }
} else {
    //do that
}
```

Comment: Thank you @MasivuyeCokile . fixed

Comment: *What about section "else do that" ?* thats your question on someone's answer, what about it also in your answer?